# Is there hotseat multiplayer in Age of Wonders: Planetfall?

Tags: age-of-wonders-planetfall

Is there hotseat multiplayer similar to AoW2 and AoW3 in console or PC version of Age of Wonders: Planetfall?

I've tried to search any official info, but was able only to find this [developer quote from 2018](https://steamcommunity.com/app/718850/discussions/0/1762481957304176774/):

> We're still working on multiplayer, so I won't be making any promises. Especially when taking console into account - it appears things like hotseat and PBEM aren't that common on those - things might be a bit different from AoW3.
>
> For PC we aim keep things as they were in AoW3, or better. But as I noted, things might still change as we work on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I found:

> Q: Can we play Hotseat with different controllers?
>   A: No, you will need to
>   pass along the controller you are using.
>
> Q: Where to I find hotseat in-game?
>   A: Go into Scenario from the main menu,
>   then go into advanced settings to be able to set up a Hotseat game.

Source: [Age of Wonders: Planetfall FAQ](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/age-of-wonders-planetfall-faq.1229790/)